# Why is $(x,y)(y,x)=|(x,y)|^2$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, proof-explanation

As part of Apostol's proof of the fact that in a Euclidean Space $V$, every inner product satisfies the Cauchy-Schwarts inequality, he states that $(x,y)(y,x)=|(x,y)|^2$. Does this not imply that (x,y) is positive, which doesn't seem like a justified assumption to me.

If necessary, I can post the rest of the proof, it is Theorem 1.8 in Apostol's Calculus Volume 2.

Answer (score 2):

Because

$$(y,x)=\overline{(x,y)}\implies (x,y)(y,x)=(x,y)\overline{(x,y)}=|(x,y)|^2$$

since

$$z\in\Bbb C\implies z\overline z=|z|^2$$

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know how I missed that! Thanks!